# Slew rate in a transmission line

Tags: voltage, current, transmission-line, slew-rate

Let's say I have a 3km long transmission line with a capacitance of C = 50pF/m, the resistance is 100Ohm. The inductance and the conductance per unit length are negligible.

If I want to receive the signal on the other end with a slew rate of 2V/1ns. I will need a current of I = C * dU/dt = 50pF/m * 3000m * (2V/1ns) = 300A.

Is my calculation and my thought process true? Do I really need 300A to achieve 2V/1ns?

Comment: At 2e9 V/s slew rate, the inductance is not negligible.

Comment: To neglect impedance or reactance per unit length at this BW means you have infinite BW and the signal arrives in zero delay so the calculation is incorrect.

Comment: " Do I really need 300A to achieve 2V/1ns?".  No!  Without going into transmission line theory, the total capacitance you calculated would be for a lumped circuit model.  The 1 ns rise time signals doesn't see this.  It just sees the distributed capacitance of the cable.

Comment: @Yoomo is this a real (lossy) or ideal transmission line?

Comment: *The inductance and the conductance per unit length are negligible* - inductance is certainly not negligible.